# Querying Project Gutenberg catalog.rdf via rdflib.js

Tags: javascript, rdf

I am attempting to interpret Project Gutenberg's `catalog.rdf` file from the browser using `rdflib.js`. Currently I am able to download a cached copy of the catalogue, parse it, and `match` a list of books. Next, I'm trying to get **all** the particulars about the book (title, author, subjects, etc.)

Unfortunately, most of my literal values are coming back as `[object NodeList]`

Example of book RDF:

```
<pgterms:etext rdf:ID="etext27785">
  <dc:publisher>&pg;</dc:publisher>
  <dc:title rdf:parseType="Literal">A Book About Lawyers</dc:title>
  <dc:creator rdf:parseType="Literal">Jeaffreson, John Cordy, 1831-1901</dc:creator>
  <pgterms:friendlytitle rdf:parseType="Literal">A Book About Lawyers by John Cordy Jeaffreson</pgterms:friendlytitle>
  <dc:language><dcterms:ISO639-2><rdf:value>en</rdf:value></dcterms:ISO639-2></dc:language>
  <dc:subject><dcterms:LCSH><rdf:value>Lawyers -- Great Britain -- Anecdotes</rdf:value></dcterms:LCSH></dc:subject>
  <dc:subject><dcterms:LCC><rdf:value>KD</rdf:value></dcterms:LCC></dc:subject>
  <dc:created><dcterms:W3CDTF><rdf:value>2009-01-12</rdf:value></dcterms:W3CDTF></dc:created>
  <pgterms:downloads><xsd:nonNegativeInteger><rdf:value>20</rdf:value></xsd:nonNegativeInteger></pgterms:downloads>
  <dc:rights rdf:resource="&lic;" />
</pgterms:etext>
```

Example of code used to parse:

```
let store = $rdf.graph();
$rdf.parse(stm,store,baseUrl,'application/rdf+xml');
let books = store.match(undefined, types.RDF('type') , types.PGb('etext')).map(t=>t.subject);
let lib = books.map(b=>{
    let props = store.match(b, null, undefined);
    console.debug("Book: " + schema['_id']);
    props.forEach(a=>{
        console.debug(a);
    });
});
```

This results in all the triples being returned, however the `object` portion is often an attempt to serialize a NodeList. For example, the "title" predicate:

```
{
  "subject": {
    "termType": "NamedNode",
    "value": "http://www.gutenberg.org/feeds/catalog.rdf#etext14600"
  },
  "predicate": {
    "termType": "NamedNode",
    "value": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title"
  },
  "object": {
    "termType": "Literal",
    "value": "[object NodeList]",
    "datatype": {
        "termType": "NamedNode",
        "value": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#XMLLiteral"
    }
  },
  "why": {
    "termType": "NamedNode",
    "value": "https://example.com/datasets/gutenberg/catalog.rdf.gz"
  }
}
```

How is it possible to get the actual value of a literal object from the RDF query?

I would also be open to other RDF JS libraries, or other query mechanisms (SPARQL for example), if that would be easier.

Comment: You're creating an array of node elements, I think you need to treat them as DOM elements to get the values which means `node.innerText`

Comment: @AminJafari I'm looking to use linked documents in general (RDF+XML in this case), not DOM.

Comment: 1. Paste your file into http://www.easyrdf.org/converter and see how (ugly) it looks in Turtle. Not sure it is possible to get all the particulars in a simple query.

Comment: Get title,author, subject in SPARQL: https://pastebin.com/7AwZLBim

Comment: @StanislavKralin I actually had tried that one, and tested it with TDBsparql, but RDFLIB.js seems to return 0 records every time. If you have an example of how to wire it up in rdflib.js that would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with rdflib.js. Perhaps it doesn't understand property paths. Try https://pastebin.com/SSu6213p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is as a direct result of a defect in the library.

RDF+XML nodes with a `parseType='Literal'` always result in `"[ojbect NodeList]"` in the browser.

https://github.com/linkeddata/rdflib.js/issues/75